# Join with intelligent separators

Tags: c#, .net, string, join

It's easy enough to write, of course, but in C# 2010, is there a built-in Join (or similar) method that will only add a separator if both the previous and next elements are non-null and non-empty?

In other words `SmartJoin(", ","Hood","Robin")` would produce "Hood, Robin" but `SmartJoin(", ", "Robin Hood", string.Empty)` would produce simply "Robin Hood".

Comment: What is the output of `SmartJoin(", ", "First", String.Empty, "Second")`?

Comment: In that case, it should be "First, Second". Sorry, my wording was misleading there...I was thinking only of a two-item list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in join which you need.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought.

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
public void SmartJoin(string separator, params string[] Items)
{
   String.Join(separator, Items.Where(x=>!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: The question was not to implement it, but to point to existing framework method that does that.

Comment: Good point, again my reading skills have failed me today.  I think it's time for a nap!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using "aggregate" method of linq

```
string result = new List<string>() { "Hood", "Robin" }.Aggregate(SmartJoin());
string result2 = new List<string>() { "Robin Hood", "" }.Aggregate(SmartJoin());

private static Func<string, string, string> SmartJoin()
{
  return (x, y) => x + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(y) ? "" : ", " + y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NotherDev was right, strictly speaking, there is no such method build in, but still @CodingGorila solution helped me, and should be added to the next .NET version by my account, though I did still turn it into a static function and have it return a string to make it work in my situation:

```
public static string SmartJoin(string separator, params string[] Items) {
    return String.Join(separator, Items.Where(x=>!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NotherDev was right, strictly speaking, there is no such method build in, but still @CodingGorila solution helped me, and should be added to the next .NET version by my account, though I did still turn it into a static function and have it return a string to make it work in my situation:

```
public static string SmartJoin(string separator, params string[] Items) {
    return String.Join(separator, Items.Where(x=>!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)));
}
```