# velocity: join optional fields with a separator/prefix

Tags: java, templates, velocity, prefix, separator

What would be the most concise/readable way in a velocity template to join multiple fields with a separator while leaving out empty or null Strings without adding excess separators?

As an example we have a tooltip or appointments that goes like:

```
Appointment ($number) [with $employee] [-] [$remarks] [-] [$roomToVisit]
```

Where I used brackets to indicate optional data. When filled in it would normally show as

```
Appointment (3) with John - serve Java coffee - ballroom
```

When $remarks is empty but $roomToVisit is not, this becomes:

```
Appointment (3) with John - ballroom
```

When instead $roomToVisit is empty we get:

```
Appointment (3) with John - serve Java coffee
```

When both are empty:

```
Appointment (3) with John
```

**Bonus**: also make the field prefix optional. When only $employee is empty we should get:

```
Appointment (3) serve Java coffee - ballroom
```

Ideally I would like the velocity template to look very similar to the first code box. If this is not possible, how would you achieve this with a minimum of distracting code tags?

Similar ideas (velocity example may help but is much more verbose):

- [Join with intelligent separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684574/join-with-intelligent-separators)
- [velocity: do something except in last loop iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196828/velocity-do-something-except-in-last-loop-iteration)

Comment: - Suggestions for other template engine that can do this are welcome - Note that I now achieve similar functionality in Java code with helper methods like "joinNonEmpty" and "prefixIfNotEmpty

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can invoke your own Java methods by registering a Java class as a tool in the context. An existing example is the [DisplayTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/DisplayTool.html). I create a VelocityStringUtil class with the methods "pre" and vararg method "join" for conditional prefix and join, and registered it as:

```
context.put("text", new VelocityStringUtil());
```

Using this, the following template creates the expected output:

```
Appointment ($number)$text.pre(' ', $text.join(' - ', $text.pre('with ', $employee), $remarks, $roomToVisit))
```

As you can see it's still a bit ugly, but I think it's better than using predefined directives (unless I am missing something).

Comment: Note that DisplayTool.list works exactly like join but with parameters switched and uses a list instead of varargs.